# Weird HTML, CSS modifications to fit requirements

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website, but I am having a hard time making my ideas come to life. I currently have a header section with a navigation bar inside of it, below that, I have code for a chat box that is centered and fixed in place. I am using `<section>` to encapsulate the chat box. I want to make the left and right side of the chat box a content area. I want these two sections to scroll in sync while the chat box stays fixed.

[image]

So the fixed areas need to stay fixed, the scroll areas need to scroll but without the content going over the line I drew. I attempted to make a content wrapper and adding padding and margins but whenever I scroll, the content kept going over it. Also it was very hard to make the left section and right section actually be on the left and right.

Here is my HTML and CSS code

```css
body {
    background-color: #2A0944;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}



.chat-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 40%;
    left: 30%;
    top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="navbar-animmenu">
        <ul class="show-dropdown main-navbar">
            <div class="hori-selector"><div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div></div>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-wrench"></i>&nbsp;Demo</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-robot"></i>&nbsp;ChatBot</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-map-pin"></i>&nbsp;About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users"></i>&nbsp;Team</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>

<body>
   
    <section class="chat-section">


        <div class="mode-selector">
            <button class="mode-button" id="normal-mode">Normal Mode</button>
            <button class="mode-button" id="material-mode">Material Mode</button>
        </div>
    
        <div class="chatbox">

          <div class="messages-container"></div>
          
          <div>
          <div class="send-section">
            <button class="clear-chat"><i class="fas fa-poo"></i></button>
            <input type="text" class="message-input" placeholder="Talk with ChatBot ..."/>
            <button class="send-button">Send</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </section>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

There is way more css thats for the items within the nav bar and the chatbox but I don't have issues with these.

My main question is what's the best way to approach adding these two left and right sections. Do I need to make changes to the current chatbox for this to work? Also how do I make scrolling keep the content under the drawn line. Thank you

Its mostly all explained above. Content wrapper was very annoying and not successful.

Comment: Your code example doesn't really look or work like you've described it.  I think it has some errors you need to address. Firsly, **ALL** of your html elements need to go inside of the `<body>` tag. You cannot just add that tag like it's any other tag.  The `<header>` must be inside the `<body>` or you should just rename that tag to something else.

Comment: The elements inside the ```<header>``` tag should be inside the ```<body>```

Comment: I added the header to the body section, everything still looks and works the same. I have not coded the left and right sections since I dont have a clear idea of how they should be added. Do I add the left section before the chat section and the right after and code them as two separate boxes? But if I do this, how would I make them stick to the left and right of the chat with symmetrical dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.  It's a 3-column flexbox layout.  The middle column is just a `<div>` but inside it is the "chatbox" that is set to

```css
width: 150px;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
height: calc(100vh - 20px);
```

- The `width` will set the width of the column (obviously)
- the `position:sticky` and `top:0px` will keep the element on screen at all times as you scroll, sticking to the top.
- the `height: calc(100vh - 20px)` will make sure the element is the same height as the window.  I just subtract 20px from it because of the 10px of padding added to both the top and the bottom.

```css
body{margin:0; padding:0;}
#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.side{
  padding: 10px;
}

#chatbox{
  width: 150px;
  background: #CCC;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
```

```html
<main id="wrapper">
  <div class="side">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="chatbox">
      This is the chatbox
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
       <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
       <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: So this got me way closer to what I am looking for, I can make the other adjustments as needed. Thank you.